# How do I get Windows Back?

Tags: 12.04

How do I get Windows back? I don't know how, I know Ubuntu is good and all, I really want to get Windows back? 
Like I want to delete the Ubuntu partition okay?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question really is, but if you want to clean install Windows (perhaps Widows 8), follow along with [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/clean-install) article written by Microsoft itself.

Comment: thanks but I hope that will help okay, I'll try, but I don't have windows 8, I'll try your way.

Answer (score 0):

If you buy the computer with pre-install the Windows, you can go to the shop and re-install the Windows.If you computer pre-install with Linux,may be Ubuntu or other Linux OS.You should buy a copy of Windows.[Microsoft Store](http://www.microsoftstore.com).